# Is it possible to read out the code from an existing .ipa from cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova

As per my Colleague, one can download any App made with Cordova/Phonegap, decompile this and have a look into all html files etc.

I think it is not possible to unpack an .ipa?

Do I have to encrypt my code? how can I be safe so that no one will have a look into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPAs and APKs are just zip files you can unzip using any archive tool.

All you can do is use tools to obfuscate your sources, but as there are also tools to de-obfuscate, it's prety useless...

Comment: For example: I have an Application where the User can login into a privat area. My Login script sends the given data (username and password) to a php script on the server. In this script i have the mysql preferences like DB-name, db-password, db-user etc. 

Is it possible for the user, after he has decompiled our app, to get to the php file, read the code and take a mysql dump?

Our login script sends not the given username, only a hash from that is send to the php file and the file then checks if the hash matches, or matches not.

Comment: The php file is not in the app, only on your server, so no it can't be accessed. Cordova apps are no more vulnerable than web pages where you just have to press F12 in the browser to get access to full source code.